# After I draw the border for CCSprite, I can't remove it

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

```
CCSprite *sprite = [[CCSprite alloc] init];
CCDrawNode *edge = [CCDrawNode node];
edge.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);
edge.position = ccp(0, 0);
CGPoint verts[4] =
{
    ccp(0, 0),
    ccp(37, 0),
    ccp(37, 37),
    ccp(0, 37)
};
[edge drawPolyWithVerts:verts count:4 fillColor:nil borderWidth:1.0f borderColor:[CCColor whiteColor]];
edge.name = @"edge";
[sprite addChild:edge];
```

After I add edge around sprite, I can't remove them.

```
NSLog(@"Children: %@", self.children);
[self removeChildByName:@"edge" cleanup:YES];
NSLog(@"Children: %@", self.children);
```

When I use method of "removeChild", I found this method can remove the edge from sprite's children list, but the edge also is shown on the iPhone's screen.

I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: what is the use of the `sprite` in the above code ? it obviously is not `self`, so if you add edge to `sprite`, you should remove `edge` from `sprite` , not `self`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have found my problem.